# Azure Pipelines: Variable not taking assigned value, instead resolves as $(variableName)

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working with Azure Pipelines and facing an issue with setting a pipeline variable using the ##vso[task.setvariable] syntax. My intention is to set the variable kaasServiceConnection with different values based on the environment parameter in the pipeline. However, when I reference this variable later in the pipeline, it doesn't seem to be taking the assigned value; instead, it seems to be resolving as $(kaasServiceConnection).

Here is the relevant snippet from my pipeline:

```
- script: |
    if [ "$(parameters.environment)" == "dev" ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=kaasServiceConnection;]SVC-DEV-CONN"
    elif [ "$(parameters.environment)" == "qa" ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=kaasServiceConnection;]SVC-QA-Conn"
    fi
  displayName: 'getting Service Connection'

- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: 'Helm upgrade'
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: '$(kaasServiceConnection)'
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would suit your case and be even a bit more native to azure DevOps pipelines.

Expressions are accepted in the variables section too, refer [conditionally-assign-a-variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-assign-a-variable)

```yaml
parameters:
 - name: environment
   type: string
   values:
    - dev
    - prod
variables:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'dev') }}:
    - name: kaasServiceConnection
      value: "SVC-DEV-CONN"
- ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'qa') }}:
    - name: kaasServiceConnection
      value: "SVC-QA-CONN"

stages:
  - stage: yourStage
    steps:
      - task: HelmDeploy@0
        displayName: 'Helm upgrade'
        inputs:
          connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
          kubernetesServiceEndpoint: $(kaasServiceConnection)
```

> Please adjust the pipeline accordingly.

Comment: This solution worked for me in the very first attempt.

Comment: glad that it helped, to help others would it be fine if you accept this as the solution/answer being the author of this post.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Parameters aren't available during runtime expressions (i.e. `$[]`) or within macro expressions (`$()`). Neither condition is evaluating to true, so the variable isn't set. The correct syntax to use for referencing parameter is compilation-time syntax, `${{ parameters.environment }}`.

The example provided above is closer to correct, although you could also do this based on the naming pattern you provided:

```
variables:
- name: kaasServiceConnection
  value: "SVC-${{ parameters.environment }}-CONN"
```

Going further, though, you should consider using a multistage pipeline, not passing an environment as a parameter.